How to efficiently Locate Source Code from Logs in SvelteKit Apps?
We have a SvelteKit App, and when bugs appear, I noticed that we spend a good amount of time locating the files and line numbers from where the logs are. (Especially for the server logs)
So I thought that this should be a common problem with an easy solution: a logging library that logs the file and the line number for every line of log out of the box and works for the Browser and Nodejs.
But this seems to be not the case. Either the logging libraries don't support it (like e.g. Pino or Winston), or you need to add some custom string parsing by throwing an error and extracting from it the file and line number, which has reasonable performance implications.
So I'm asking myself

Is it 2024 still not possible to have this out of the box somehow without the performance implications?
Or is the question about file and line number the wrong question, and there are other good options to locate the piece of code connected to a log message?

